Vue v-model with objects
Sometimes my environment requires components that are stand-alone (i.e. does not rely on a store/pinia of some stripe) but have complex needs in terms of how they are supplied props.
If I have a component in VueJS that takes a v-model that is of type Object:
<ChildComponent v-model:foo="bah" />

let's suppose bah is something along the lines of:
// ParentComponent.vue
<template>
  <ChildComponent v-model:foo="bah" />
</template>

<script setup>
const bah = reactive({
  foz: '',
  baz: -1,
  ...
})
</script>

we can't do something simple like the samples on https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html
the usual pattern I take is to deep clone the prop to a local ref (either onMounted or via a watch depending on the situation)
// ChildComponent.vue
const props = defineProps({
  foo: { type: Object, required: true } 
})

const d_foo = ref(null)

// in the instance that the parent only stipulates foo onMounted
onMounted(() => {
  d_foo.value = cloneDeep(props.foo) // lodash/cloneDeep
})

// on some occasions I may expect that foo has been modified before hitting the component, in which case I would use
watch(props.foo, val => { 
  d_foo.value = cloneDeep(val)
}, { deep: true })  // deep true, if applicable

but this can lead to bloat.  Somehow, the component needs to emit to the parent.  For example:
watch(d_foo, val => { 
 emit('update:foo', val)
}, { deep: true })  // if props.foo is being watched, some provisions may need to be made, but that is beyond the scope of this question.


The question, then, is:
if I declare that a child component has say: defineEmits(['update:foo'])
and the parent has v-model:foo="bah"
then why, beyond the needs of convention, should I care about my code policing every emission?
why couldn't I (using the object above) have the following field in my child component:
<input v-model="foo.foz" />
assuming bah has been initialized properly (with ref or reactive) and has an explicit interface (e.g. I defined all its properties when I assigned it to the declaration; I could even have enforced its format as a prop with a validator), data will be mutated on the parent in this context.  I've been working now for many years with Vue and I still think this is something of a grey area.

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that reflects the expected relationship between the components and their states. What you describe can look a few different ways. You can do <input v-model="foo.bah.foz" in a child if foo is child's own state, e.g. it's deep cloned from a prop. And you can't do this if foo is a prop, because this would result in mutating parent's state in a child, which is a bad practice

no problem, updated.

I see. Yes, the "bloat" example is how it if a child needs to have its own state for some reason, e.g. debounce the updates or partially change the state, like in your case. What's the problem with  part? You can do this in that example

If you don't need child's own state for other reasons, the alternative is to use custom events instead of v-model to partially mutate the parent's state in a parent. Because deep cloning on every change can become inefficient with large state. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/79028365/3731501 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/78941552/3731501

If ChildComponent has a prop called foo and you assign a property of that foo to an input's v-model inside ChildComponent, you will be mutating the parent's foo without knowing it  i.e. <input v-model="foo.bah" />. Instead you would have to do <input v-model="d_foo.bah"> and watch the change on d_foo and then emit that.  it gets bloated really quickly.

Yes, that's correct. "foo" should be cloned foo prop, i.e. d_foo in your case. Btw what's about the name with d_ prefix, is this some convention? I saw it already in third-party libs.

I use it to delineate "data" clones of a prop.  So If i have prop foo, the local ref will be d_foo (in options API it would've gone in the data object). likewise for c_foo if I was doing something with computed getters and setters (not viable in this instance of course!)

As I say, it is "correct" to go with <input v-model="d_foo.bah" /> I just question what it is about the reactive system of VueJS that sees mutation of the prop directly (as I give above) <input v-mode="foo.bah" />" as a problem.  It's so much extra boilerplate, if the parent has an explicit object interface (as I mention above).

Thanks, d_ makes sense. This isn't a "problem" problem with reactivity, i.e. this doesn't cause errors or unexpected behaviour, at least in most cases. This is a known design problem though, mutation of a parent's state result in spaghetti code that is hard to debug and maintain, especially at many levels of nesting, and may potentially cause performance issues. Vue is able to restrict this for shallow prop mutations but not for deep.

Afaik prop mutation proved itself very inefficient in Angular 1 (which Vue copied), 2-way binding was changed in A2 (which it was heavily inspired with too), so now religiously discouraging prop mutation is considered good )) Though deep prop mutations don't differ much from deep state mutations in general, which Pinia doesn't oppose for some reason, for instance. As said, this is more a bad practice rather than technical problem.

I think your question could be answered with the official VueJS docs if you check out whats under the hood of v-model itself
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#under-the-hood
Beside using the new Vue 3.4+ macro helps getting rid of some boilerplate, have a look at the docs
https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#definemodel

I'm aware of the aforementioned macro, @Sanderr; I have even written my own reactive system to the spec for vue's "reactivity in depth" in the past. I don't think Vue's docs have ever really given an elegant solution to the volume of boilerplate required here, quite honestly.  Not all environments I work with are ^3.3 (much as I wish they were) In fact, I'm working with 2.7 a lot and I'm retro-fitting the question above to a broader audience.

If previous versions where you miss out on those sugar syntax, then yes you need some boiler plate. But the way implemented it is by adding additional (cloned) state in the parent which isn't recommend in general. You better implement it like described in the docs or in complex scenarios you can try writable computed properties
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed

@Sanderr A macro can be expressed manually with a writable computed, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/79009268/3731501 , this is ok for <input v-model="foo">  but not for <input v-model="foo.bar"> because nested properties aren't handled by computed's "set" trap

I'm relaying this from a reddit discussion I had on the same subject:
https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/1ftnali/comment/lpu5vb5/?context=3
thanks to https://www.reddit.com/user/redblobgames/ for this one:

I think the main reason is that it changes the interface in a subtle way that's not apparent in the interface.
Here's a scenario based on a real-world problem I had (and a simplified vue playground):
We have a . Next year we want to change the parent point representation to be polar, with r: and angle: instead of x: and y:.
So we change the parent, and use <ChildComponent :location="polarToCartesian(point)" @update:location="point = cartesianToPolar($event)">. Maybe we use computed() with a setter to encapsulate this pair of conversions.
Under normal Vue conventions where children do not modify props, this change should work fine.
However, if the child mutates props directly, the code will break, because it's modifying the temporary value instead of the actual location. It's not something that's apparent in the interface, which only says that the v-model is a point with x: y:. And the bug may not be noticed right away, depending on how often that value is modified.

an excellent point.
as for alternatives I have found that vueuse has a discrete tool for the job:
const props = defineProps({
  foo: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  })

const emit = defineEmits(['update:foo'])
const foo = useVModel(props, 'foo', emit, { deep: true, passive: true, clone: true })

this will emit foo changes correctly even where a local field has modified a single property of the object (it uses a watcher under the hood so the usual caveats apply around huge objects etc.)

the both solutions in your answer don't offer anything new that wasn't already discussed and rejected.

in the reddit solution the object is cloned
in useVModel solution the object is deeply mutated (which is bad) and just an extra update:model event added sending already mutated object.


Propose an alternative to cloning the prop/the above please.  If you can think of a succinct alternative without a heap of boilerplate then you should post an answer here and - quite honestly - blog it.  Remember, this is for stand alone components that do not use vuex/pinia/provide|inject etc.
I will investigate vueUse's useVModel now.

incidentally, yes the above requires the clone option set to true. that's amended (you can also supply lodash's cloneDeep etc.)
What is your objection to cloneDeep?  It's going to depend on your use thereof.  I wouldn't use it in all instances but for relatively small objects (even with 2 or 3 dimensions and several properties in each) it is perfectly performant.  Stand alone components aren't going to need humongous objects; probably shouldn't do either really.

yes, i've mentioned that v-model for small plain objects only in my answer, but deleted the answer. Cloning v-model for complex objects isn't a solution since an object could be a complex class instance with circular references so you cannot just simple copy it

Yes, I take your point; if one were using typescript you could specify that the object have specific properties and enforce against complex classes with circular references. Either way, my discussion is stand alone components; such things ought to be properly documented with/without ts.
If this is a component available to 3rd party developers: the vueUse clone method uses JSON.parse(JSON.stringify) which will safely handle circular JSON with an exception allowing you to feedback to the client.

(just as a sidenote, any clone library worth its salt should handle circular references. Lodash's cloneDeep also handles circular references safely)

silly but structuredClone() doesn't, afaik

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/structuredClone handles circular references according to MDN.  I've just tested that in chrome and they appear to behave safely (it would be extraordinary if modern browsers caused recursive loops with a global)

lol, mistaken with JSON.stringify

Can you just take the object key as a props?
// Paren.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue';

const bah = ref({
  foz: '',
  baz: -1,
})
</script>

<template>
  {{bah}}
  <ChildComponent v-model="bah" modelKey="foo" />
</template>

// Child.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{
  modelKey: string;
}>();
const model = defineModel()
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="model[modelKey]"/>
</template>

Vue SFC Playground

unfortunately, that will mutate the model-value prop
pop the following into the app.vue of your playground (apologies for no spacing, you'll need to \n it):



It would be more visual to create an example on the same Vue SFC Playground. It's not difficult.  Because I don't quite understand what you are talking about.

I wanted to but I could't as it's too long for the comments. Here's the correction shortened with some extra deets: https://shorturl.at/Hkbl2
Observe that the event never triggers.

I think I finally understand your question and what you want )) https://shorturl.at/kS3rH

As a rule you shouldn't ever mutate props, even if you're emitting as well.  So once again, unfortunately, that is incorrect.  defineModel is not designed to handle objects and the VueJS docs need to do a better job of teaching 2-way object management. there are numerous pitfalls.
My solution above is my personal preference but, yes, requires cloning; thus, should only be used sparingly where the object would be a nuisance to manage with props.

I do not agree with you. defineModel handles objects well.

It isn't a question of agreeing/disagreeing: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#mutating-object-array-props
from the docs: The main drawback of such mutations is that it allows the child component to affect parent state in a way that isn't obvious to the parent component, potentially making it more difficult to reason about the data flow in the future. As a best practice, you should avoid such mutations unless the parent and child are tightly coupled by design. In most cases, the child should emit an event to let the parent perform the mutation.
